# Grep : Windows version, free alternative?

Tags: windows, grep, find-and-replace

I am trying to source a tool for performing a search and replace of text files in a directory.

I think this is similar to what grep does for linux. I was hoping to find a tool with a gui so I could find all files that contain a text string and then replace it.

Don't want to use cygwin to use grep. Grep for Windows appears to only work for 30 days and is 30$

Anyone know of another similar tool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the free [`GNUWin32`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) packages, which contain most of the common command-line utilities found on *nix systems, including `grep`. Spend a little time learning `awk` and `sed` and you won't need any GUIs.

***EDIT***

There are several free/cheap text editors that have much of the functionality you're looking for built-in. My personal favorite is [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com), as it's cross-platform, and many people like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which is only available for Windows.

Comment: Or just use notepad++. It's what I do when I'm forced to use windows and can't install what I want as freely.

Comment: @SBI I was considering mentioning Sublime Text 2, perhaps I will now...

Comment: It's obviously not the best option, but it gets the job done and requires minimal time spent installing.

Comment: I never realized that Sublime Text 2 supported this, I have just tested it and it works great! Thanks

Comment: Sublime is great, I love it!